# How to sort by specific dots - single or multiple

Tags: java

My input is a List of String as follows

Prefix1-Prefix2-PartA.PartB.PartC

Need to sort until PartB number changes...After sorting PartB. Need to sort PartC with descending

```
M-P-100.55.23D
M-P-100.50.23A
M-P-100.55.23A
M-P-100.55.23D
M-P-100.60.23A
M-P-101.50.23D
M-P-101.50.23E
M-P-101.50.21A
M-P-101.50.21E
M-P-100.60.23D
```

Expected is wanted to sort until the number changes after 100/101 i.e 55 or 50 or 55. and the last one to be sorted by desc. Once the number changes again it will sort the number but the last one would be sorted by desc

```
M-P-100.55.23D
M-P-100.50.23A
M-P-100.55.23D
M-P-100.55.23A
M-P-100.60.23A
M-P-101.50.21E
M-P-101.50.21A
M-P-101.50.23D
M-P-101.50.23E
M-P-100.60.23D
```

How to do this in java? I `List.sort()` or `Array.sort()` cannot be used for this as it can sort the entire as ascending or descending only. Can someone suggest the best way to achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to achieve. "sort until the number changes after 100.", "One the number changes again it" These are ambiguous and unclear sentences

Comment: sorry..updated...see the number after the first dot...need to sort after the first dot until the number change...the last portion would be desc order

Comment: What is "until the number change"? I still don't get it. This post can be clearer if you will mark each portion of the format and give each portion a name, then explain exactly what the is needed order.

Comment: For example - data format - <Character 1>-<Character 2>-<Number 1>.<Number 2>.<Two digits number><Character 3>

Comment: If you want to sort PartB by ascending, and PartC by descending order, the expected output is wrong.

Comment: why it is wrong? can you please tell me

Comment: For starters, how come `M-P-100.55.23D` comes before `M-P-100.50.23A`? If you can't describe the goal, we won't be able to answer..

Comment: 100.55.23D followed by 100.50.23A...So it should be same....If 100.55.23D, then 100.55.23E, then 100.55.23C then sorting should happen....Until the center number changes the sorting should be done in the chunk alone...when a different number comes..then we need to sort the next chunk...Basically chunk by chunk sort

Comment: PartD is mentioned in the question but, it's not in the format. I think I got what you are saying. but, in the case of 4 consecutive 50(row 6 to 9), shouldn't the expected result will be this order? `23E, 23D, 21E, 21A` (assume the prefixes are there)

Comment: You are right Ankit

Comment: Sliding window `start` and `end` that you can pass the `sublist` into the sorting with a custom `Comparator`, whenever you come across a change to `PartB`.  once you're done shift the window and start again.